# jquery slideToggle strange effect

Tags: jquery, html, slidetoggle

This is an example of code I have created to explain the situation.
It works well but when it toggle to hide the tbody, it does a estrange effect (first expands the tbody by three or four times more than it is and then it collapses straigh away, and when it slide down it will also do it straigh away).

When slide down it is not a problem for me, but when collapses it is.

Could you give a hand on this?

Thanks

Code.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
        $(".tblGeneral thead").click(function() {
        $(this).next(".tblGeneral tbody").slideToggle("fast");
        });
        });
      </script>
</head>
<body>
 <table class="tblGeneral">
      <thead>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="2">Title</td>
         </tr>
    </thead>
     <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="title">Name:</td>
            <td>Some name</td>
       </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</body>
```

Comment: Which browser?  Working fine here in FF and Chrome

Comment: I am using IE7, sorry for late reply.

Comment: Works in IE7 here too, something else is going on it looks like

Comment: As I said on the question, it does work, but there is a strange effect, when section its expanded, and it has to collapse section, it expand it more and then collapse, at this point I would assume that its the expected behaviour of slidetoggle.

Comment: I'm getting a smooth, single slide down and slide up, nothing abnormal, is there some CSS at play here, if so can you post?  Might be having an effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey, you want to apply the css

```
position: relative;
```

to your table, that should fix the issue.

so in your case, it would be

```
.tblGeneral { position: relative; }
```